# Can I make a home made yeast from non gmo flour?

Tags: yeast

Can I make yeast from gmo flour 
and can I use it for gmo flour to make a dough.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify it. What do you mean by "make yeast from GMO flour"? Where does "non-GMO flour" come into your question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just bear in mind that "yeast" is a technical term for a type of fungus, I think what you're looking for is culturing this fungus in flour... If you can post the recipe you're planning on using that's better.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really "make" yeast.  It must be cultured in the appropriate medium.  Yeast can be purchased in freeze dried or fresh form and added to flour and other ingredients for baking.  You can also culture yeast by creating and maintaining a starter.

As of two years ago there was no commercially produced genetically modified wheat, at least in the US.  I am guessing that has changed by now, but there is nothing about that process that would impact the way flour interacts with yeast spores.  So, GMO or not, it should not matter.  Given the correct process, you should be able to create a starter.

Comment: Also, wild yeast can be found anywhere. My grandma swore that the best yeast for bread making comes from apple peels.

Comment: Thank you for reply, how to make it with apple peels